# Group Booking through Amadeus APIs

Tags: amadeus

I am looking for set of APIs that will help me perform Group Bookings without passenger names. Initially I want to perform a Group Booking by mentioning the journey / sector details and the passenger count. At later point, once I know the Passenger Names, I want to update the Group Booking with the passenger names. Please suggest the corresponding APIs for this.

Tried to get the concerned API from online documentation, but didnt find any.

Basically I am trying to achieve this from API - https://servicehub.amadeus.com/c/portal/view-solution/856016/how-to-create-a-group-booking-graphic-